# How to find Ramp landing space and Intermediate landings in Revit API?

Tags: revit-api, autodesk, revit

I am trying to find Landing Spaces as well as Intermediate Landings for Ramps using Revit API, for a few of my models. So far I have tried to find Start and Endpoints of the ramp using location parameters as mentioned in the following blog space ([How to find start/end of ramp in revit, perhaps with sketches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699537/how-to-find-start-end-of-ramp-in-revit-perhaps-with-sketches)) , but it seems that this parameter is unavailable in the models I am trying to use.
 I tried to explore any other way using Revit API functionalities but with no visible success so far. Also, I am new to Revit Api's and as such have a limited understanding of what features are available in API.

Can someone help me Identify Ramp Landings or Ramp endpoints?

[Ramp Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZFVu.png)

[Ramp Property Pallete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06t2A.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible approaches:

- Location
- Sketch
- Geometry

Using the `Location` property, casting it `LocationCurve` and grabbing the endpoints from that as suggested in the other discussion you link to would be the optimal solution.

Another approach mentioned in that thread is to use the sketch defining the ramp to determine its start and end points. Getting hold of the sketch elements is not completely trivial, but absolutely doable, as explained in The Building Coder discussions on

- [Stable Reference Relationships](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/02/stable-reference-relationships.html)
- [Retrieving and Snooping Dependent Elements](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/03/retrieving-and-snooping-dependent-elements.html)

If all else fails, the final alternative would be to grab and analyse the ramp geometry to deduce the required information from that.